# what should be the output of MPI_COMM_WORLD in a cluster of 4 machines and 4 processes?

Tags: mpi

I am trying to learn how to use MPICH2 for parallel programming. I have sucessfully setup a virtual cluster using  virtual box which has one master and 3 slaves. All have 4 core cpus. When I try to run a program on a single machine with -np 4 and print the MPI_COMM_WORLD output it says 4, which is ok because of the 4 processes. But when launched on the cluster with arguments -np 4 -f hosts , the ouput of MPI_COMM_WORLD is still 4 , I guess it should have been 16, since there are 4 processes on 4 machines.

Can anybody explain what am I doing wrong ?
Does MPI launch the same program on every machine or  just the part where  parallel code starts.

Comment: What do you mean you "print the `MPI_COMM_WORLD` output"? How you do that? What programming language? Please post your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-np <np> 
        specify the number of processors to run on
```

you should use `-np 16` if you want to use 4 nodes and 4 processes per node.